# Vacuum test in the laboratory

Tags: experimental-physics, vacuum, humidity

If I put some water in a plastic container and apply a vacuum pressure of -0.20bar the water comes out of plastic container which should  not as per design and material of container. This is called Air tightness failure. Please tell me what should be relative humidity inside the vacuum desiccator  to avoid this.

Comment: If the container isn't tight it will remain as such

Comment: ‘Vacuum dessicator’ and ‘relative humidity’ do not belong together.